# Retaining variables in dcast

Tags: r

I am using the `dcast` function in R to turn a long-format dataset into a wide-format dataset.  I have an ID number, a categorical variable (CAT), and a continuous variable (AMT).  However, I also have a variable SEX, which is the same for all rows of a given ID number.  This code works to create the wide-format dataset, but I lose SEX.  How can I retain it?

```
PC1cast <- dcast(PC1, ID~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If I add SEX to the ID~CAT line, it gives me SEX-CAT combinations.  I want SEX to just be one value for each row.

Comment: Please show example data

Comment: I created an example data and this works though `dcast(PC1, ID+SEX~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)` if `SEX` is the same for all rows of a given `ID`

Comment: ID   CAT   AMT   SEX
1      A         46      Female
1      B         22      Female
1      C         31      Female
2      A         17      Male
2      B         25      Male
2      C         44      Male

Comment: Can you check the output in the solution.

Comment: That does it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data showed

```
dcast(PC1, ID+SEX~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#  ID    SEX  A  B  C
#1  1 Female 46 22 31
#2  2   Male 17 25 44
```

#### data

```
PC1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), CAT = c("A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C"), AMT = c(46L, 22L, 31L, 17L, 25L, 44L), SEX = c("Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male")), .Names = c("ID", 
"CAT", "AMT", "SEX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```